# What's the best way to retry publishing messages with kombu?

Tags: python, kombu

I'm testing how kombu works. I'm planning to replace pika in several projects.  I see that kombu has a lot of documentation but using what I found in the documentation some messages are lost. Here it's the code:

```
from kombu import Connection, Producer
conn = Connection('amqp://localhost:5672')
def errback(exc, interval):
     logger.error('Error: %r', exc, exc_info=1)
     logger.info('Retry in %s seconds.', interval)
producer = Producer(conn)
publish = conn.ensure(producer, producer.publish, errback=errback, max_retries=3)
for i in range(1, 200000):
   publish({'hello': 'world'}, routing_key='test_queue')
   time.sleep(0.001)
```

When it's publishing I close the connection several times and it keeps publishing but in the queue there are around 60000 messages, so there are a lot of lost messages.

I've tried different alternatives e.g:

```
publish({'hello': 'world'}, retry=True, mandatory=True, routing_key='hipri')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

The problem was that by default Kombu doesn't use 'confirm', you have to use:

```
        conn = Connection('amqp://localhost:5672', transport_options={'confirm_publish': True})
```

Thanks

Comment: Nice for sharing this.

Comment: This doesn't do what mandatory flag in Pika does. If there are no queues declared on RabbitMQ Server the message will be sent and will not be routed to any queue and therefore will be "ignored". The producer won't receive any signal of the message is not routed.